# Mimic printStackTrace() method in java

Tags: java, exception, printstacktrace

My question Is there is any way to implement a method that works like the `printStackTrace()`
I don't know how to start doing this indeed , Is that possible ?
Is `getStackTrace()` is a good choice for me.

Comment: I believe the community decides whether to vote up/down, not the OP.

Comment: Sysout each entry of `getStackTrace()`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic since OP doesn't show any effort.

Comment: @bblincoe just a note :)

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera just need a start point

Comment: I was the downvoter. I think that it's a **must** to downvote when *there's need to*. This way you can learn what questions should be ask here and how to improve them in the future. Downvotes are good as upvotes when they're explained.

Comment: Why would you need to duplicate the printStackTrace behavior? What does it lack? Perhaps there is an easy way to achieve your goal without duplicating functionality that is already present

Comment: If you want to reinvent a wheel, look at the wheel and see how it works. Surely you have your JDK's sources. If you have an objective in mind, which would give your question a purpose, you should have said so. and, as Ruricha noted, you should have tried yourself first. SO is a Q&A, not a tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the official way how it is done ([grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/Throwable.java#Throwable.printStackTrace%28java.lang.Throwable.PrintStreamOrWriter%29) format):

```
646  private void printStackTrace(PrintStreamOrWriter s) {
647      // Guard against malicious overrides of Throwable.equals by
648      // using a Set with identity equality semantics.
649      Set<Throwable> dejaVu =
650          Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<Throwable, Boolean>());
651      dejaVu.add(this);
653      synchronized (s.lock()) {
654          // Print our stack trace
655          s.println(this);
656          StackTraceElement[] trace = getOurStackTrace();
657          for (StackTraceElement traceElement : trace)
658              s.println("\tat " + traceElement);
660          // Print suppressed exceptions, if any
661          for (Throwable se : getSuppressed())
662              se.printEnclosedStackTrace(s, trace, SUPPRESSED_CAPTION, "\t", dejaVu);
664          // Print cause, if any
665          Throwable ourCause = getCause();
666          if (ourCause != null)
667              ourCause.printEnclosedStackTrace(s, trace, CAUSE_CAPTION, "", dejaVu);
668      }
669  }
```

A bit more concerns are handled than you would anticipate, but you can easily remove any you don't care about.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the stack trace for any moment, you could try this:

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();// this return an array of StackTraceElement loop over in order to print them.
```

or if you just want to get the stack trace in case exception, just use `ExceptionUtils` from `apache common` libraries.

```
ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(ex);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the help of `Throwable` class. See the code below:
The method return the stacktrace.

```
public String tracePoint()
{
    String trace = "";
    Throwable t = new Throwable();
    StackTraceElement[] s = t.getStackTrace();
    for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++)
    {
        trace += s[i] + "\n";
    }
    return trace;
}
```